# Sending integer values from RPi to Arduino serially

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

Current scenario: I have a program running on my Pi that calculates a couple of values from an image and OpenCV, two of those values being 'pulse counts' that I want to send to an Arduino with stepper drivers attached.

I have just been running a small test code for my Pi:

```py
import serial
YpulseCalc = 200

serial1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
serial1.flush()
YpulseCalc = str(YpulseCalc)
YpulseEncode = YpulseCalc.encode()

while True:
    if (serial1.in_waiting > 0):
        serial1.write(YpulseEncode)
```

My Arduino code is as follows:

```cpp
// Initialize values needed
int yPulseCalc = 0;
int xPulseCalc = 0;

// defines pins numbers
//Front left wheel
const int stepX = 2;
const int dirX  = 5;

//Front right wheel
const int stepY = 3;
const int dirY  = 6;

//Back left wheel
const int stepZ = 4;
const int dirZ  = 7;

//Back right wheel
const int stepA = 12;
const int dirA = 13;
const int enPin = 8;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Sets the two pins as Outputs
  pinMode(stepX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepZ, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirZ, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirX, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirY, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirZ, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirA, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    yPulseCalc = Serial.read();
    xPulseCalc = Serial.read();

    Serial.print("yPulseCalc: ");
    Serial.println(yPulseCalc); 
    delay(5000);
    //Serial.print("xPulseCalc: ");
    //Serial.println(xPulseCalc);
  }
}
```

One thing I don't understand is when I pull up the serial monitor for the Arduino, it is blank until I click the "Send" button once, even if the input box is blank. It then begins to receive various values, 12, 50, 48, 48, 48, etc., but not the '200' I sent. Can anyone explain that?

The values I will be sending range from something like -500 to 500; not sure if that changes any methods of writing it.

Comment: what is your understanding of this line `serial1.in_waiting > 0`

Comment: and which arduino are you using ?

Comment: Use `Serial.parseInt()` to read a string from a serial port and convert it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423121/12570891):

12, 50, 48, 48 are the ASCII bytes for the string "\f200". It appears you are sending an ASCII representation of your numbers from Python, and trying to interpret the received bytes as numbers on the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

From your Raspi code:

```
 if(serial1.in_waiting > 0):
        serial1.write(YpulseEncode)
```

From your Arduino code:

```
if(Serial.available() > 0)
{
  yPulseCalc = Serial.read();
  xPulseCalc = Serial.read();
  Serial.print("yPulseCalc: ");
  Serial.println(yPulseCalc); 
 ...
```

So both programs only read/write from/to the serial interface if there is at least 1 byte in their respective input buffer.

If both are waiting for the other one nothing will ever be communicated.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you are sending data from the Raspberry you don't have to wait for incoming data first, so you can remove the `in_waiting` line:

```
if(serial1.in_waiting > 0):  # remove this line
    serial1.write(YpulseEncode)
```

**2.** From the Raspberry you are sending a string (a binary value converted to string), but on the Arduino you are reading the bytes as numbers.

So the string `"200"` contains the chars (bytes) `'2', '0', '0'` which have ascii values of `50, 48, 48` which is what you see on the Arduino.

To solve this you can either read a string on  the Arduino, or send the value as binary.

To read as string:

- on Raspberry add a newline to the string:

  ```
    YpulseEncode += '\n'
    serial1.write(YpulseEncode)
  ```
- then on Arduino use:

  ```
    String result;

    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        result = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        // ...
    }
  ```

See [here](https://roboticsbackend.com/raspberry-pi-arduino-serial-communication/) for some more examples.